# Как сделать появление текста при прокрутке страницы

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Как можно сделать на сайте, чтобы при прокрутке вниз появлялся текст(просто появлялся без выдвижений), а после прокрутки текста, он постепенно исчезал.

Пример: `https://intranetboy.webflow.io/`

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Предложу такой вариант с появлением и исчезанием текста при скроле...

```js
let t
const o = document.querySelector('#txt')
document.querySelector('#container').addEventListener('scroll', _ => {
  if (t) clearTimeout(t)
  o.classList.add('on')
  t = setTimeout(_ => o.classList.remove('on'), 1000)
})
```

```css
#container {
  height: 200px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
#container > div {
  height: 2000px;
}
#txt {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 50px;
  right: 50px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  transition-property: opacity;
  transition-duration: 2s;
  opacity: 0;
}
#txt.on {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <div><div>
<div>
<div id='txt'>Пример текста<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно вот так это сделать:

```js
const txt = document.querySelector("#txt");


window.addEventListener('scroll', e => {
  if (pageYOffset >= 220) {
    txt.classList.add("op");
  } else {
    txt.classList.remove("op");
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  min-height: 500px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.txt {
  margin-top: 300px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s;
}

.op {
  opacity: 100;
}
```

```html
<div id="txt" class="txt">Какойто текст Какойто текст Какойто текст Какойто текст Какойто текст Какойто текст Какойто текст Какойто текст Какойто текст Какойто текст Какойто текст Какойто текст Какойто текст Какойто текст Какойто текст Какойто текст Какойто текст Какойто текст Какойто текст Какойто текст Какойто текст Какойто текст Какойто текст Какойто текст Какойто текст Какойто текст Какойто текст Какойто текст</div>
```